# Get hostname mapped to IP Address from file similar to hosts file using BASH

Tags: bash, hosts

I have a file similar to hosts file where IP Address is mapped to hostname.
Below is a snapshot of file

```
20.200.80.15   slave1
20.200.80.16   slave2
20.200.80.17   slave3
20.200.80.18   slave4
20.200.80.19   slave5
20.200.80.20   master1
```

I would like to retrive Hostname from IP Address from the above file using `bash script` i.e. if I supply ipaddress as `20.200.80.18` then i should get output as `slave4`

Comment: you need to learn bash yourself if you decide to use bash as your tool. your request is as easy as `grep $ip $file | awk '{ print $2 }'`, or fully in awk: `awk '$1 == "'$ip'" { print $2 }'`, need to pay more attention on quote handling.

Answer (score 1):

The script could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
        echo "Usage: myscript.sh IP";
        exit 1;
fi;

IP=$1
HOSTS_FILE=/root/hosts_test

grep -F "$IP " "$HOSTS_FILE" | awk '{ print $2 }'

exit 0;
```

And you call it like:

```
sh myscript.sh 20.200.80.16
```

It is important to use the `-F` option in grep (or use `fgrep`) so te dots are considered as litterals and as not regex wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip=$1
file=$2
grep $ip $file | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

and running the script like this:

`getHost 20.20.20.20 /etc/ipfile`